# Реализовал такую конструкцию , но как сделать переход до якорей по hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3

Много раз видел подобное меню в сети , само такое конечно сделал но :

1. Как убрать из адресной строки имя `ID`
2. Как сделать переход до якорей по `hover`
3. Как отровнять другие блоки как и `первый`

Пример в песочнице : [codepen](http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/mELRKr?editors=110)

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  text-decoration:none;
}
menu{
  height:50px;
  background:#fff;
  line-height:47px;
}
ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:.1em 1em;
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
  outline:1px solid #eee;
}
ul>li>a{
  color:blue;
}
.l:after{
  content:"";
  border:5px solid transparent;
  border-top:5px solid blue;
  position:absolute;
  right:2px; top:48%;
}
.l .menu{
  position:absolute;
  top:51px; left:0;
  width:600px;
  height:300px;
  background:#fff;
  border:10px solid #fff;
  outline:1px solid #eee;
  display:none;
}
.l:hover .menu{
  display:block;
}
.tab{
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#fff;
}
.paginator,.content{
  float:left;
  height:100%;
}
.paginator{
  width:30%;
  background:#fff;
}
.content{
  width:70%;
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
}
.view{
  width:95%;
  height:95%;
  outline:1px solid #eee;
  margin:1px 2%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.paginator p{
  border:1px solid #eee;
  margin:0 0 3px 0;
  padding-left:4px;
}
.paginator p:focus,
.paginator p:hover{
  background:#eee;
}
.paginator p a{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  color:blue;
}

.view div{
  width:90%;
  height:90%;
  margin:10px auto 30px;
}
.p1{
  background:#ccc;
}
.p2{
  background:#000;
}
.p3{
  background:#cc0000;
}
.p4{
  background:#30dd30;
}
```

```html
<menu> 
  <ul> 
    <li><a href="">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Гостевая</a></li>
    <li class="l"><a href="">Примеры</a> 
      <div class="menu"> 
        <div class="tab"> 
         <div class="paginator"> 
           <p><a href="#d">Изображения</a></p>
           <p><a href="#c">Смайлы</a></p>
           <p><a href="#b">Книги</a></p>
           <p><a href="#a">Кино</a></p>
          </div>
         <div class="content"> 
           <div class="view"> 
             <div id="d"class="p1"></div>
             <div id="c" class="p2"></div>
             <div id="b" class="p3"></div>
             <div id="a" class="p4"></div>
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">О нас</a></li>
  </ul>
</menu>
```

Я естественно понимаю что не реально переходы до якоря `id="?"` сделать по `hover` на `css`  но ума не приложу как делается такое на `js`, плиз растолкуйте как такое делается и особенно про **первый пункт** и **второй** ?

Comment: третий пункт решил самостоятельно

Comment: http://loftblog.ru/material/preprocessor-jade-ustanovka-i-bazovoe-ispolzovanie/  здесь пример такого меню

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем вам в принципе якоря? Вам нужно чтобы срабатывал селектор li:hover + div. А в div уже размещайте что хотите.
Вот пример:

```css
li {
  padding: 1em 2em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#withsub {
  position: relative;
}

#withsub ul {
  position: absolute;
}

#withsub li {
  position: relative;
}

#withsub li + div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

li:hover + div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item#1</li>
  <li>item#2</li>
  <li id="withsub">item#3 &or;
    <ul>
      <li>subitem#1</li>
      <div style="background-color: #d00;"></div>
      <li>subitem#2</li>
      <div style="background-color: #0d0;"></div>
      <li>subitem#3</li>
      <div style="background-color: #00d;"></div>
      <li>subitem#4</li>
      <div style="background-color: #dd0;"></div>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>item#4</li>
</ul>
```